# Map object list in jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

Jsp page code to map list of objects in iterator tag, i  want 'que' and 'optns' property form this objects list

```
<s:iterator value="objects" >
<s:property value="%{#playerPredictionLevel2.que}"/>

    <s:property value="que"/>

    <s:property value="#playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID.optns"/>
</s:iterator>
```

java code for getting value from database

```
List<Object[]> objects=null;

    public String indexView() {

        objects = getDaoFactory().getPlayerPredictionLevel2Dao()
                .findByTName();

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Hibernate query to fetch data but there is not any relationship between them, so i created list of objects for that

```
public List<Object[]> findByTName() {
        List<Object[]> list = null;
        list = getSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "From PlayerPredictionLevel2 as pp,PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2 as po where pp.optionRefNo = po.playerPredictionLevel2Id  ")
                .list();

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: i will not able to map property from the object list in iterator

Comment: The list contains an array of Objects that you cannot use to map corresponding properties in the model. You can instead use a constructor query (JPA) to execute this query on a class with corresponding properties to fetch a list of rows from the database (not sure about plain Hibernate).

Comment: list of objects in JSP with the unknown type should be converted to the valid java bean, so you can bind its properties to the corresponding fields.

Answer (score 0):

you are not specfiy `ArrayList()` while creating object.
try this,

```
    List<Object[]> objects=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Comment: i have created getter setter for the object List and in iterator i check that for length of object list iterator is moving but i am not able to show data

Comment: could you post moving object?what you got?..it somewhat help for us.@CHiRAG

Comment: i have upload image of that @hari

Answer (score 0):

Just check your action class for proper getter setter of the field objects like as following

```
public List<Object[]> getObjects() {
    return objects;
}
public void setObjects(List<Object[]> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
}
```

And in JSP iterate your list as following way

```
<s:iterator value="objects" status="status">
        <s:property value="que"/>
</s:iterator>
```

OR

```
<s:iterator value="objects" status="status">
        <s:property value="%{#status.que}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

[image: this is the object data view while retrieve data using query]

Comment: i have try this but still not produce any output

Comment: @CHiRAG  
Hi try following code  
<td><s:property value="%{objects[#status.index+1][#status.index+1].getYourFiedName()}"/></td>

Comment: hi Mahesh what do you mean by index +1

Comment: <s:property value="%{objects[#status.index+1].getQue()}"/> you mean like this

Comment: Just try following snippet   <s:iterator value="objects" var="parent">
       <s:iterator value="#parent" var="child">
       <tr>
        <td><s:property value="#child.que"/></td>
       </tr>
      </s:iterator>
      </s:iterator>

Comment: but in our case we dont have any relation between two table

Comment: Yes chirag i know that but above code will gives you output. Have you tried or not?

Comment: Mahesh its done but in objest list one object for question and other for its option so how can i differenciate in this scenarion